# Does parallellization in R copy all data in the parent process?

Tags: r, doparallel, domc

I have some large bioinformatics project where I want to run a small function on about a million markers, which takes a small tibble (22 rows, 2 columns) as well as an integer as input. The returned object is about 80KB each, and no large amount of data is created within the function, just some formatting and statistical testing. I've tried various approaches using the parallel, doParallel and doMC packages, all pretty canonical stuff (foreach, %dopar% etc.), on a machine with 182 cores, of which I am using 60.

However, no matter what I do, the memory requirement gets into the terabytes quickly and crashes the machine. The parent process holds many gigabytes of data in memory though, which makes me suspicious: Does all the memory content of the parent process get copied to the parallelized processes, even when it is not needed? If so, how can I prevent this?

Note: I'm not necessarily interested in a solution to my specific problem, hence no code example or the like. I'm having trouble understanding the details of how memory works in R parallelization.

Comment: These questions are very hard to answer in the general case. All data needed for processing will be copied to the worker threads. It would easier to see some specific code to see why more data than you are expecting is being exported.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining the exact situation. You say, you have a million markers but only two columns of 22 rows. Does that mean your "markers"  are combined in text strings? And what does your function do with these text strings? Have you profiled memory requirements with a subset of your data?

Comment: The rows are subjects (yes, I know, the study is massively underpowered, but the disease is extremely rare), the integers are binary representations of a 0-1 factor variable used as a predictor. There are about a million of them.

Comment: @MrFlick Obviously, the data required is copied. In my case, the large data is not required nor passed to the function anywhere, hence my question. I think a better way to phrase it might be if the entire R environment of the parent process is copied.

Comment: Have you looked into multidplyr? You have to specifically define which variables are passed to the child processes.

Comment: It would really be helpful to have a code example. Have you tried specifying `.noexport` in `foreach`?

Comment: The function is set up to look at the symbols in your code and export what it finds by default. Things can get tricky when formulas are involved or other objects which hold references to entire environments. By default the entire environment shouldn't be exported, but there are certainly cases when the default variable detection might go awry. It's impossible to really make a good guess as to what's going on without seeing code.